# Docker: Localhost didn't send any data

Tags: docker

This is my Dockerfile contents:-

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/public
VOLUME src/ /var/www/html/public
EXPOSE 800
```

Then I run this command.

`docker run -p 80:800 final`

So I tried to access the localhost, but it returns 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

Earlier it was giving 403 error.

OS - Mac

**[Edit] Adding more detail**

[image: Error found in docker terminal]

[image: 403 error in browser]

Comment: Can you tell us what web-server are you trying to run(adding the `FROM` line missing from your Dockerfile should be enough to reproduce).

Comment: Hi @NeoAnderson, Please check, it was hidden earlier.

Comment: Apache probably doesn't listen on port 800…!?

Comment: @deceze I have tried with port 80 initially, then I run 80:80 at the terminal, but 403 error was getting.

Comment: As the error says, you don't appear to have any `index.*` file in your directory, so Apache doesn't know what to serve you for `localhost:8000/`.

Comment: @deceze Oh, now I got it. I give a search on autoindex:error and I found exactly what you caught. 

Thanks for informing. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `php:7.0-apache` image listens by default on port `80`. The `EXPOSE` you are using in the `Dockerfile` does not change that.

Normally, you have no reason to try an change the default listening port of the container, hence it has it's own IP address and you should never run into a port conflict problem.

The port election might be an issue on the host and in this regard you may chose to publish on any port that is not in use.

If you simply swap `80` and `800` in your docker run command, you shall be able to access the web-app at `localhost:800`

The following command will create a DNAT rule from your host machine port `<src>` to the container port `80`, making it possible to visit the web-app at `localhost:<src>`

```
docker run -p <src>:80 final
```

---

**Edit answering forbidden problem update:**

The `php:7.0-apache` image will look for an index.* under `/var/www/html/`. Your Dockerfile is copying the source into `/var/www/html/public`.

Comment: Yes, I did the same, I expose the port at default 80, then I run the command like you said in last, but now I am getting 403 error. I will add the screenshot above.

Comment: Hi Neo, Just added, please check. The first screenshot was of my terminal,

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to reproduce, but I don't have a Mac :)

Comment: Neo, Problem is solved, as suggest by @deceze. Thanks a lot for giving the above info. :)

Comment: Yes, got to the same answer: make sure you are copying the index under `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Yes, now I understood. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi, recently I dockerized one of my projects, my project in docker was created and started smoothly, and in my docker-compose file ports are configured to '${APP_PORT:-8000}:8000' but in docker container it shows port 80, and when I click to open te laravel app in browser it is not responding ?